# should primary key of OneToOne owning side be non-incrementing?

Tags: database, database-design, doctrine-orm, relational-database

I use doctrine. I have several oneToOne entities. The PK of owning side is FK too. So I have to set this pk to be NON auto-increment?

Comment: In most cases just leave your primary keys at auto-increment.  I know there is a temptation with one to one relations to want to have the same primary is for both entities.  But there is seldom any value to it and it just complicates things.

Comment: Anyway for OneToOne relation better to have it auto incremented or not?

Comment: Thanks. I hope delete a parent entity and cascade deletion and adding another association later will not be broken.